# What is the meaning of Default/NativeImage in fuslogvw?

Tags: .net, assembly-resolution

I occasionally use fuslogvw to track down problems loading assemblies.  After all my time of using it, it seems that the folder 'NativeImage' has results for loading native images of my dlls.  When the native image is not found (usually its not), I think it then looks for a .net assembly.  The 'default' folder is what I normally care about, because it has logs for all assembly bindings, which is where my problem typically lies.

Can anyone explain the real difference here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The native images are the JIT-compiled versions of the DLLs. If they are not present, the non-JIT-ted versions are located and used.

[This article](http://web.archive.org/web/20100813121241/http://www.grimes.demon.co.uk/workshops/fusWSTwelve.htm) explains native images in more detail and how to use them with fuslogvw.