# .NET Fusion logger: What is the difference between Default and Native Images?

Tags: .net, assembly-resolution, fusion

In the .NET fusion logger (FUSLOGVW.exe) what do the two options in the [lower right of the screen](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BackToBasicsUsingFusionLogViewerToDebugObscureLoaderErrors.aspx) do?

```
 Log Categories
  + Default
  + Native Images
```

And how can I use either one to diagnose a mixed-mode assembly problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the meaning of Default/NativeImage in fuslogvw?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/944633/what-is-the-meaning-of-default-nativeimage-in-fuslogvw)

Comment: The questions ARE similar, but the accepted answer starts with "I think."  This one already has a much more detailed answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Native images are the files generated by ngen.exe.  It contains pre-compiled machine code for an assembly, so that the JIT compiler isn't needed.  All .NET framework assemblies are ngen-ed.  They have the .ni.dll filename extension.

You are typically not interested in them if you are trying to troubleshoot an assembly resolution problem.  But you can see them getting loaded if you choose "Native Images" instead of "Default".

Comment: Where do mixed mode assemblies fall between those options?

Comment: They are just another assembly that contains IL.  Fusion doesn't care about the unmanaged bits in it.